# JSON parse error with one value

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I've been trying to figure this issue out for far to long. Right now I'm getting a value similar it this from a data API: `"[Test-text]"`

What I want is to convert this to an array so I can loop through the values. I tried using `JSON.parse("[Test-text]")` but I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

When I add another value like this:

```
JSON.parse("[Test-text, test-text2]"))
```

it works. If I can't parse one value, is there any work around for this that will work? Also, I need to be able to store one value because the value that I'm trying to parse is from a list of checkboxes that the user will control, if they select one, one will be returned.

Comment: Neither of your examples work because they're not valid JSON. Are you expecting an array of strings? Then each element needs to be wrapped in double quotes: `'["Test-text"]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Json you need a Key/Value Pair

```
["key":"Value"] //does not work
```

and it has to be wrapped in a object e.g (its an array of objects) :

```
[{"key":"value"}]
```

So its just an Object

```
{"key":"value"}
```

And you can put objects in objects

```
{"key":{"depth1Key":"value"}}
```

Or Arrays in a Object

```
{"key":['value','val']}
```

etc....
Read more about by yourself

Comment: You can have an array as the root object too: `["value"]` is valid JSON.

Comment: yes your right but i think there are not many cases this makes sense.. or ?

Comment: I think the OP's JSON should be: `["Test-text", "test-text2"]`.

Comment: This is correct. It needs to be like this `'["Test-text"]'` which I will need to have changed in my api. Thanks!